# Kendo for Angular - Grid: two rows for each data item

Tags: angular, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

Is it possible to render two rows for each data item in the kendo grid for Angular?
The grid is very narrow and we need to have a textual description for each data item which has no space in a extra column.

#### Example:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">This is the first employee.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">This is the second employee.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the detail row template to add the textual description. The detail rows are expanded by default in the component.